# Copying directories with .toml files to Docker container

Tags: python, docker, file, data-structures, dockerfile

I need to copy all directories that contain `.toml` files from the host machine into a Docker container while preserving the original directory structure. However, the `COPY **/*.toml ./` instruction in my Dockerfile only copies the individual `.toml` files, not the directories.

Here's a simplified version of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

# Install required packages
RUN pip install toml

# Copy directories with .toml files
COPY **/*.toml ./
```

How can I modify the Dockerfile to copy the directories containing `.toml` files while preserving the directory structure? I appreciate any help or alternative approaches to achieve this.

Comment: COPY does not have such functionality, you can use `find` with exec option  to copy .toml files preserving the directory structure before doing `docker build` and then copy this directory to your image in the dockerfile.